# Unit testing and global testing for custom CMS

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, testing

At the company, we are writing a micro-CMS from scratch, in PHP + MySQL. It allows to create a multidomain + multilanguage + e-commerce platform, with administration part. As we are not using any framework, I wonder how could we implement some unit tests and modular test to correct any bugs that may slip through the code. The code is completely procedural. It has grown from a few files to a huge amount of code and tables and we are envisioning that it may be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/207401/writing-tests-for-existing-code